# Ansible Tower - How to get a list of the environment variables

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-awx

Within Tower there is a lot of options to add environment variables before execution.  I have set some variables that get pulled into a python inventory script.  However the script is responding with an error.   I think the python code is not getting the values or the values are not in the correct format.

I would like to see how the environment variables are being exposed to the python script.  Is there a way to get these added to the debug output in the job log?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I wasn't executing a playbook.  I was executing a custom python inventory script and I need to be able to see how Ansible was loading the variables to be able to troubleshoot why the script wouldn't load the variables.  I added some code to the python script to send me an email with the list of environmental variables.  You can also write this to a file on the drive, but if you are using tower, you have to expose the folder location under the admin settings -> Jobs -> paths to expose.  I decided it would be easier to just get an email while testing.

```
import smtplib
import datetime
import time
ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
output = ""
output +=('Time Start {} \r\n '.format(st))
for a in os.environ:
output +=('Var: {} Value: {} \r\n'.format(a, os.getenv(a)))
def send_email(addr_from, addr_to, contents):
svr = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mail.local', 25)

msg = 'Subject: Subject goes here.\n\n{0}'.format(contents)
svr.sendmail(addr_from, addr_to, msg) 
send_email('addr_from@mail.com','addr_to@mail.com',output)
```

Here is a picture of the variables

[image: tower environmental variables]

Then here is a picture of the script.

[image: bad script]

But this didn't work.  Here is the code that worked.

[image: good code]

The problem was that when you query the environmental variable in python, if its a dictionary, it will return with single quotes and you have to convert that to double quotes and json.loads it to get it to load as a dictionary.

There is multiple problems solved with this.  I hope this helps others needing to troubleshoot Ansible with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Just use debug along with the 'env' lookup.Below `home` is the environment variable.

```
- name: Show env variable
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('env','HOME') }}"
```

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/env.html